# Android AsyncTask How to Set Timer

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i am new in Async Task android

i just really have one simple question.. please tell me where to look for if this question has been asked before

i am using AsyncTask

my doInBackground in this asynctask is used for POST Request to my Own Server

but sometimes, when my server is down maybe because of electricity or another problem,

this AsyncTask will load forever

and while the asynctask still running, i open my computer, and the server is up again, but the async task still running and loading forever until i close the program, and run in back

i dont want my user to experience it

**i guess, what i want is**

**making the async task to run doInBackground for like 20second, and after 20 second, if there is still no result , then i will do something**

how do i do that?

should i make another thread for this 20 second? 
or is there any timer that can be set to asynctask..

thanks before..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a timeout for the network operation. That way, it will throw an exception if this timeout is exceeded.

For example, if using a `DefaultHttpClient`, it would be something like:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = client.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
```

If it's an `HttpUrlConnection` instead, use:

```
connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
connection.setReadTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
```

where `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` and `SOCKET_TIMEOUT` are in milliseconds.